# Haskell - specifying kind in data declaration

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, types, higher-kinded-types

In this declaration

```
data Const a = Const Integer
```

Haskell infers that `Const` is `* -> *`. Is it possible to make `Const` take a type constructor instead, so it will be `(* -> *) -> *`? Ideally, it should be `a -> *`, but there are no polymorphic kinds. [This thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell@haskell.org/msg10185.html) shows one solution - adding unused constructor. Has the situation changed since 2002?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're right, since GHC doesn't support polymorphic kinds, it will do kind defaulting to `*`.

However, using the `KindSignatures` extension, you can explicitly annotate a data declaration with a specific kind:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data Const (a :: * -> *) = Const Integer
```

Or, if your a fan of  [GADT](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GADT)s:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Const :: (* -> *) -> * where
  Const :: Integer -> Const a
```

You can now write:

```
x :: Const Maybe
x = Const 2
```

---

I just compiled the original program with the experimental [Utrecht Haskell Compiler](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/UHC) (UHC).

The UHC doesn't really compile any real world programs, but it does support kind polymorphism! Its interesseting to see it infer:

```
-- kind of data type:
Const :: forall a . a -> *

-- type of constructor:
Const :: Integer -> forall* a . forall b(a) . Const b
```